Tikz forest. grow east Issue with arrows. How to keep them straight?
For my flow chart, if I do not use grow=east option for the tree, it does not fit the page width.
Using grow=east makes it fit. But now the arrows connecting the nodes no longer are straight as they are in the default case. Here is what I have now.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={font=\sffamily,
      grow=east,
      line width=1pt,     
      fit=rectangle,
      forked edge,
      edge={thick, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
      }
%
[main API, text width=3em ,
 [dsolve(),  draw=black
   [first order ode, draw=black
       [different module for each ode type, text width=7em , inner sep=2pt, draw, double copy shadow, fill=white   
           [first order initial conditions process, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered, draw]  
       ]
   ]
   [second order ode, text width=7em , inner sep=2pt, text centered, draw
       [different module for each ode type,text width=7em, draw, double copy shadow, fill=white
           [second order initial conditions process, text width=6em , inner sep=2pt, draw]  
       ]
   ]  
   [higher order ode solver,  text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, draw
       [higher order initial conditions process, text width=10em , inner sep=2pt,draw]     
   ]
 ]
 [dsolve\_BVP() \footnotesize{(not yet implemented)},   text width=8em, draw=black
    [second order ode boundary value problem module, text width=12em , inner sep=2pt,  draw]
 ]
 [{\small dsolve\_reduction()}, draw=black
    [second order ode solved using reduction of order, text width=10em , inner sep=2pt,  draw]
 ]
 [dsolve\_series(), draw=black
    [series ode solver, draw]   
 ]
 [dsolve\_sys(), draw=black
   [system of ode solver,  inner sep=2pt,  draw]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

lualatex gives

I understand why this happens. Since the arrow has to go from middle of one rectangle edge to the middle of the second rectangle edge. And if these two rectangles are not exactly same size, the arrow will have to make abrupt change.
I can fix this by removing   forked edge option to the tree. But I do not like the output

The question is, is there a trick to keep the arrow horizontal straight but without the bends? They do not have to go from middle of rectangle to middle of the other rectangle. That is not important, I just do not like how the forked edges look now when the tree grows east.
What is the correct way to fix this?
For reference, this is how it looks using default top-down (i.e. without using grow=east. I like the top down, but for the problem that it does not fit the page.


calign with current edge?

Add anchor=center to your for tree.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={font=\sffamily,
      grow=east,
      line width=1pt,     
      fit=rectangle,
      forked edge,
      anchor=center,
      edge={thick, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
      }
%
[main API, text width=3em ,
 [dsolve(),  draw=black
   [first order ode, draw=black
       [different module for each ode type, text width=7em , inner sep=2pt, draw, double copy shadow, fill=white   
           [first order initial conditions process, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered, draw]  
       ]
   ]
   [second order ode, text width=7em , inner sep=2pt, text centered, draw
       [different module for each ode type,text width=7em, draw, double copy shadow, fill=white
           [second order initial conditions process, text width=6em , inner sep=2pt, draw]  
       ]
   ]  
   [higher order ode solver,  text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, draw
       [higher order initial conditions process, text width=10em , inner sep=2pt,draw]     
   ]
 ]
 [dsolve\_BVP() \footnotesize{(not yet implemented)},   text width=8em, draw=black
    [second order ode boundary value problem module, text width=12em , inner sep=2pt,  draw]
 ]
 [{\small dsolve\_reduction()}, draw=black
    [second order ode solved using reduction of order, text width=10em , inner sep=2pt,  draw]
 ]
 [dsolve\_series(), draw=black
    [series ode solver, draw]   
 ]
 [dsolve\_sys(), draw=black
   [system of ode solver,  inner sep=2pt,  draw]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


If you prefer to have the tree grow down (and do not wish to rotate it), the folder style can make very economical use of space for the right kind of tree. This also avoids the need to force line breaks and/or tolerate hyphenation. You could also remove or increase the inner sep, if you wished, or further increase l sep or s sep.
Note that the effect of l sep and s sep is somewhat counterintuitive (at least to me) when folder is in force, so alter only one at a time to see what it does. But this could just be me. They both do what they say on the tin.

Alternatively, I'd do slightly more to align things and use calign=edge midpoint to straighten the arrows, which lets you use anchor=parent.
I'd then override calign for the two cases where the child's edge is just slightly displaced from the parent's.

Aesthetically, I prefer the first. However, depending on the meaning, the second might be more pedagogically functional.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/718526/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    font=\sffamily,
    grow'=-0,
    line width=1pt,     
    edge+={thick, -{Triangle[]}},
    folder,
    l sep'+=5pt,
    s sep'+=5pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={content+=\strut},
  },
  for descendants={draw},
  [main API ,
  [dsolve()
    [first order ode
        [different module for each ode type , inner sep=2pt, double copy shadow, fill=white   
            [first order initial conditions process , inner sep=2pt]  
        ]
    ]
    [second order ode , inner sep=2pt
        [different module for each ode type, double copy shadow, fill=white
            [second order initial conditions process , inner sep=2pt]  
        ]
    ]  
    [higher order ode solver , inner sep=2pt
        [higher order initial conditions process , inner sep=2pt]     
    ]
  ]
  [dsolve\_BVP() \footnotesize{(not yet implemented)}
      [second order ode boundary value problem module , inner sep=2pt]
  ]
  [{\small dsolve\_reduction()}
      [second order ode solved using reduction of order , inner sep=2pt]
  ]
  [dsolve\_series()
      [series ode solver]   
  ]
  [dsolve\_sys()
    [system of ode solver,  inner sep=2pt]
  ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\clearpage
\begin{forest}
  for tree={font=\sffamily,
    grow=east,
    line width=1pt,     
    fit=rectangle,
    forked edge,
    edge={thick, >={Triangle[]}, ->},
    calign=edge midpoint,
    anchor=parent,
    tier/.option=level
  },
  delay={where={> On= {level}{1}  }{%
      for descendants/.process={ Ow {id} {tier+={#1}}
      },
    }{},
  },
  [main API, text width=3em ,
  [dsolve(),  draw=black
    [first order ode, draw=black
        [different module for each ode type, text width=7em , inner sep=2pt, draw, double copy shadow, fill=white   
            [first order initial conditions process, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered, draw]  
        ]
    ]
    [second order ode, text width=7em , inner sep=2pt, text centered, draw, calign with current edge
        [different module for each ode type,text width=7em, draw, double copy shadow, fill=white
            [second order initial conditions process, text width=6em , inner sep=2pt, draw]  
        ]
    ]  
    [higher order ode solver,  text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, draw
        [higher order initial conditions process, text width=10em , inner sep=2pt,draw]     
    ]
    ]
    [dsolve\_BVP() \footnotesize{(not yet implemented)},   text width=8em, draw=black, calign with current edge
        [second order ode boundary value problem module, text width=12em , inner sep=2pt,  draw]
    ]
    [{\small dsolve\_reduction()}, draw=black
        [second order ode solved using reduction of order, text width=10em , inner sep=2pt,  draw]
    ]
    [dsolve\_series(), draw=black
        [series ode solver, draw]   
    ]
    [dsolve\_sys(), draw=black
      [system of ode solver,  inner sep=2pt,  draw]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

